# SwipeListView front bug click 2.3 android

Tags: android, listview, click, swipeview

Implemented SwipeListView 47 Degrees library, work fine, but on android 2.3.* not working click on back view -  front view always catch click event. Googling gave no results.
Maybe, someone found solution how to implement click  on back view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this library works perfectly swipe on android 2.3.* versions https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView